# How to configure a fte ant script so it can perform few task before file transfer

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

can any one please suggest me some good sites so i can learn how to use FTE & FTE ant script. Basically i want to wite ant script to perform few task before file tranfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it .. below is the solution for reference:

```
<request version="1.00" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FileTransfer.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <managedCall>
      <originator>
         <hostName>X.com</hostName>
         <userID>X</userID>
         <mqmdUserID>X</mqmdUserID>
      </originator>
      <agent QMgr="X" agent="X"/>
      <reply QMGR="X">reply</reply>
      <transferSet priority="1">
         <metaDataSet>
            <metaData key="com.ibm.wmqfte.SourceAgent">X</metaData>
            <metaData key="com.ibm.wmqfte.DestinationAgent">X</metaData>
         </metaDataSet>
         <call>
            <command name="X.xml" type="antscript" retryCount="2" retryWait="30" successRC="0">
               <target>X</target>
               <property name="trigger.filename" value="${FileName}"/>   

            </command>
         </call>
      </transferSet>
      <job>
         <name>X</name>
      </job>
   </managedCall>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

[WMQ InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/using_ant.htm) has good information on FTE Ant scripting. You can also look at this [developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1206_thambrahalli/1206_thambrahalli.html) article.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of how to call fte ant script from monitor.

Comment: I don't think you can call a fteAnt script from a FTE Monitor as it is used as directory or queue monitoring purpose and initiates a file transfer when a conditions are met.